# How to call back parameter?

Tags: c#, class, parameters

I want to set `textbox.text` from `class1`, but when I press the button nothing happens. What's wrong?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Class1 c;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c = new Class1();
            c.x();
        }
    }
}
```

And this code from `class1`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static Form1 f;

        public void x()
        {
            f = new Form1();
            f.textBox1.Text = "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

I already change the `textBox1` modifier to public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `f = new Form1()` you create a new form. If you already have an instance of `Form1` open then this will give you two instances of `Form1`. Calling a method on one of them won't affect the other. You have to pass a reference of your form to your instance of `Class1` and call the method on that reference.

There are different ways to do this. One could be to pass the reference as an argument to the `x` method:

```
public void x(Form1 f)
{
    f.textBox1.Text = "hello";
}
```

When you call `x` you can pass it the special variable `this`, which is the object that the code is associated with. That will pass your instance of `Form1` to `x`, so that `x` can use it.

```
c.x(this);
```

Comment: can you give me example,sory i am new in c#

Comment: Thnx Marcus @Marcus Karlsson

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c = new Class1(this);
    c.x();
}


class Class1
{
    public static Form1 f;

    public Class1(Form1 form)
    {
        f = form;
    }

    public void x()
    {
        f.textBox1.Text = "hello";
    }
}
```

The problem is that you create a new Form1 instance in the x method. Change your code according to my snippet and it will work.